# Finding the set of cluster points for an interval that is closed and open

Tags: calculus

I need help with finding the set of cluster points for [0,1). How do cluster points work if an interval is closed and open?

Comment: Hello, since you deleted your question, I'm posting an answer to it here in the comments. It's an alternative solution. We want to prove: $\gcd(a,b)=1,\ d\mid a,\ d\mid bc\implies d\mid c$. We know $d\mid a\implies a=dm$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$. Then $\gcd(dm,b)=1$, so $\gcd(d,b)=1$, so by [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $d\mid bc\implies d\mid c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be non empty, recall that $x$ is a cluster point of $A$ if for any $r>0$ we have 
$$\left((x-r,x+r)\setminus\{x\}\right)\cap A\neq\emptyset$$

Thus from the definition you can see that any $x\in(0,1)$ is a cluster point, because if $x\in (0,1)$ you can always find $r>0$ such that $(x-r,x+r)\subseteq (0,1)$

Also you can see that $0$ and $1$ are cluster points. Because for any $r>0$, we have 
$(0,r)\cap[0,1)\neq\emptyset$ which implies $((-r,r)\setminus\{0\})\cap [0,1)\neq\emptyset$, so $0$ is a cluster point. Similarly $1$ is also a cluster point.

Finally for any $y\notin [0,1]$, we have $y\in[0,1]^c$. As $[0,1]^c$ is open, we can always find $r>0$ s.t. $(y-r,y+r)\subseteq[0,1]^c$, so in this case $y$ is not a cluster point.

Hence the set of cluster points of $[0,1)$ is $[0,1]$

Comment: So how does it work for 1, if it is open? Is it just the same idea that it has "neighborhoods"?

Comment: For any $r>0$, we have $(1-r,1)\cap[0,1)\neq\emptyset$, thus  $((1-r,1+r)\setminus\{1\})\cap[0,1)\neq\emptyset$, thus $1$ is a cluster point

Comment: Ahhh okay. And what does the backslash mean?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A\setminus B$ means "remove $B$ from $A$". For example, $(-r,r)\setminus\{0\}$ means "remove the point $0$ from $(-r,r)$", which is the same as $(-r,0)\cup(0,r)$.